# Insert and Select query at the same time

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access

- `Table1` (`name, carname`)
- `Table2` (`carname, agency`)

I executed the following command

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into Table1 values('"+name+"','"+carname+"')");
```

and the value is inserted.

At the same time if the `carname` in `Table2` is the same as user given it has to select the agency. How can I write the query? (This two process has to be done at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do them "at the same time", Access isn't capable of multi-threading.  The only way to do it is to run the statements in succession, or one after the other.  If that's the case, just put a second INSERT staement into an If/Then/Else block and only run it if it fulfills your desired criteria.  I honestly don't understand the question; are you trying to match up the last record inserted?  If that's the case, just select the Max(PrimaryKey) and INNER JOIN it back to the table, and that will give you the record you last inserted.

Comment: For eg:if user give carname as tata that car name have to insert the Table1 and in the Table2 for carname tata some agency name will be already there that agency name have to be selected and display from Table2 @Johnny Bones

Comment: So can't you just run a SELECT query immediately after the UPDATE statement like "SELECT Agency from Table2 WHERE Carname = '"+carname+"'" ?